# How long does it take to approve apps on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-messenger-bot

I applied for app review 6 days ago for **a chatbot** and Facebook has **not yet** returned an answer for this review, how much time it take usually? Everything that facebook require for precheckout is ok.

Comment: It used to say 5 business days back when the old system was in place, and depending on what features you submitted, it could easily be double that. I doubt however that those time frames are still realistic/up-to-date after the recent changes, that require review for a lot of already existing apps, and more features - bet they must be pretty swamped right now. You’ll just have to wait, until you get notified about updates regarding your app’s review status.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 - Permissions and features review**

This step takes 7 business days to be reviewed.

I had submitted my chat bot on May 27, 2018 and got past this review step on Jun 6, 2018

**Step 2 - Business Verification**

If you use the messenger API then your business needs to be verified (license, utility bill) etc. and also you need accept the supplemental terms.

You need to create a Business manager account and link it to your app.

You then need to provide the proofs for verification.

Finally, you need to sign the supplemental terms and apply for review.

References -

[1] New App Review Requirements - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review